# Webserver behind NAT, do I need to enable port forwarding for request port?

Tags: sockets, networking, webserver, router, nat

It's kind of a trivial question, but I couldn't really find a good answer to it.

When I host a webserver behind a NAT that listens on port 80 it's obvious that I need to enable port forwarding to port 80 of the webserver in my router. However, 80 is just the server's accept port and for the actual request it will be using a different temporary random port.

My question is, do I also need to enable the port forwarding for this random port that is now being used for the request or not? If not, how does it work, I mean how is it magically getting through the NAT then?

Let me cite from a book: 
"A server (program) runs on a specific computer and has a socket that is bound to a specific port. The
server listens to the socket for a client to make a connection request (see ). If everything goes
well, the server accepts the connection. Upon acceptance, the server gets a new socket
bound to a different port. It needs a new socket (consequently a different port number) so that it can
continue to listen to the original socket for connection requests while serving the connected client."

[image: New on different port opened by server]

I just want to know if this "new connection" works for a client that is out on the Internet, if port forwarding is only enabled to the listening port of the server behind the router.

Answer (score 0):

At the TCP level the server always will be using port 80, there is no random port here. Of course there will be a new socket but this is because a socket represents a connection (serverIP, 80, clientIP, clientPort).

The networking gateway maps the client (ip,tcp port) to a unique address/port on the inside of the network and keeps track of that in a table. In the simplest case the translated address will be the private address of the gateway and the port could be the same. When the server responds (from port 80 to the translated address/port) the gateway looks up the table, translates back the addresses in the packet headers and sends the translated packet to the client over the internet.

Here is an example trace I copied from [here](http://www.rogerclarke.com/II/IPrimerhttp-dump.html). You see that the server at 192.168.0.102  always responds from port 80. The browser seems to be opening a couple of ports 1046 and 1047. In this example both the client and server are in the same subnet but assuming NAT 192.168.0.103 could be an address of the gateway and 1046, 1047 might be translated ports. Ports could be translated two times if there is also a gateway in front of the browser.

```
5   14:52:49.543851  192.168.0.103.1046 > 192.168.0.102.80: S 7861110:7861110(0) win 8192 <mss 1460> (DF)
6   14:52:49.543851  192.168.0.102.80 > 192.168.0.103.1046: S 3595122238:3595122238(0) ack 7861111 win 32736 <mss 1460>
7   14:52:49.543851  192.168.0.103.1046 > 192.168.0.102.80: . ack 3595122239 win 8760 (DF)
8   14:52:49.653851  192.168.0.103.1046 > 192.168.0.102.80: P 7861111:7861361(250) ack 3595122239 win 8760 (DF)
9   14:52:49.663851  192.168.0.102.80 > 192.168.0.103.1046: . 3595122239:3595123699(1460) ack 7861361 win 32736 (DF)
10  14:52:49.663851  192.168.0.102.80 > 192.168.0.103.1046: P 3595123699:3595124724(1025) ack 7861361 win 32736 (DF)
11  14:52:49.663851  192.168.0.103.1046 > 192.168.0.102.80: . ack 3595124724 win 8760 (DF)
12  14:52:50.803851  192.168.0.103.1047 > 192.168.0.102.80: S 7862363:7862363(0) win 8192 <mss 1460> (DF)
13  14:52:50.803851  192.168.0.102.80 > 192.168.0.103.1047: S 3701480536:3701480536(0) ack 7862364 win 32736 <mss 1460>
14  14:52:50.803851  192.168.0.103.1047 > 192.168.0.102.80: . ack 3701480537 win 8760 (DF)
15  14:52:50.873851  192.168.0.103.1048 > 192.168.0.102.80: S 7862437:7862437(0) win 8192 <mss 1460> (DF)
16  14:52:50.873851  192.168.0.102.80 > 192.168.0.103.1048: S 2553725067:2553725067(0) ack 7862438 win 32736 <mss 1460>
17  14:52:50.873851  192.168.0.103.1048 > 192.168.0.102.80: . ack 2553725068 win 8760 (DF)
18  14:52:50.973851  192.168.0.103.1048 > 192.168.0.102.80: P 7862438:7862753(315) ack 2553725068 win 8760 (DF)
19  14:52:50.993851  192.168.0.102.80 > 192.168.0.103.1048: . ack 7862753 win 32736 (DF)
20  14:52:50.993851  192.168.0.102.80 > 192.168.0.103.1048: . 2553725068:2553726528(1460) ack 7862753 win 32736 (DF)
21  14:52:50.993851  192.168.0.102.80 > 192.168.0.103.1048: P 2553726528:2553726886(358) ack 7862753 win 32736 (DF)
22  14:52:50.993851  192.168.0.103.1048 > 192.168.0.102.80: . ack 2553726886 win 8760 (DF)
23  14:52:51.023851  192.168.0.103.1047 > 192.168.0.102.80: P 7862364:7862677(313) ack 3701480537 win 8760 (DF)
24  14:52:51.023851  192.168.0.102.80 > 192.168.0.103.1047: . 3701480537:3701481997(1460) ack 7862677 win 32736 (DF)
25  14:52:51.023851  192.168.0.102.80 > 192.168.0.103.1047: . 3701481997:3701483457(1460) ack 7862677 win 32736 (DF)
26  14:52:51.033851  192.168.0.103.1047 > 192.168.0.102.80: . ack 3701483457 win 8760 (DF)
27  14:52:51.033851  192.168.0.102.80 > 192.168.0.103.1047: P 3701483457:3701484633(1176) ack 7862677 win 32736 (DF)
```

Search for NAT and PAT there are many good resources to fully understand how this works in more detail.

Comment: Please see my edit, I don't think I had asked the question right.

Comment: Write to the author (Buyya of "Obj. Oriented Programming with Java", right?) that he is wrong, a new socket is of course needed but not a new port, definetely not a new TCP port. In my opinion the author has attempted to "paraphrase" http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/definition.html which is careful not to go down the port inaccuracy. Look at the diagrams in the book and the link I provide to see what I mean, there is no new TCP port!!!

Comment: What I still don't understand though is, that if there is no new  port then all communication of ONE client with the server would block the listen port so no other clients could connect. Or is it really so as stated in the link you sent me that one port can be used for multiple socket connections? I've always learnt one port = socket, otherwise the resource is busy. Is it something Java specific that I can open multiple sockets on one port or is it generally designed to be so in a networking? Could you point me to resources clarifying this?

Comment: One port is not one socket. One TCP socket "is" one (serverIP, serverPort, clientIP, clientPort) as I wrote in my answer. So the server port can be the same (i.e. 80) and in your code still have several sockets because they refer to different clientIP/ports.